# IOS-Ask the user for play song in uiwebview media player

Tags: ios, uiwebview, media-player

If I click on the mp3 url in a `UIWebView`, It pops the media player to play the mp3 automatically.
But here what I am need is just ask confirmation from the user to play the song in `UIWebview` media player.Is it possible to access `UIWebview` media player? If it is how?
Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to ask confirmation from the user.

User UIWebView delegate method :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
self.URL = [request URL];
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    AVURLAsset* asset;

    self.songURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.URL];

    //Check for supported song formatted 
    if([self.songURL hasSuffix:@".mp3"] ||
       [self.songURL hasSuffix:@".wav"] ||
       [self.songURL hasSuffix:@".aiff"] ||
       [self.songURL hasSuffix:@".aac"] ||
       [self.songURL hasSuffix:@".m4a"] ||
       [self.songURL hasSuffix:@".m4p"] ||
       [self.songURL hasSuffix:@".caf"])
    {

        asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:self.URL options:nil];

        if(asset != nil)
        {
            UIActionSheet *actSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Songs"
                                       delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:@"Download"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Listen Online", nil];
            [actSheet showInView:self.view];
        }
        [asset release];
        return NO;

    }
}
return YES;
}
```

And on UIActionSheetDelegate method:

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(buttonIndex == 1)
  {
     [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.URL]];
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the UIWebview media player pop up when a url contain ".mp3" in suffix?

Comment: Yes,It is possible.You have to check for ".mp3" in suffix. And if it contains .mp3 return YES to directly play it.And in else check for other extension and return NO.